# What is the use of "Algo" word?

Tags: meaning

I've seen the `Algo` word in some websites for sorting content.

What does it really means?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Please remember to demonstrate your initial research efforts; for example, a simple web search on *algo sorting* turns up many results for *sorting [algorithms](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/algorithm)*. I encourage you to take the site [tour] and review the [help] for additional guidance. Our sister site for [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/tour) may also be of interest.

Comment: Wikipedia says [*ALGO is an algebraic programming language developed between 1959 and 1961 for the Bendix G-15 computer.*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ALGO) But I'd be more inclined to say *it **was** an algebraic programming language...*

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about an English word, or the use thereof.

Comment: You need to describe the context much better to expect an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Algo is commonly shorthand for algorithm.  An algorithm for sorting content is the method by which content is grouped and ordered. [Oxford Dictionary*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/algo_)

ex) A search engine's sorting algorithm for search term results may order the results weighted by physical proximity, how closely the result is matched to the search phrase, and perceived topical relevance.

*Reference thanks to @marcellothearcane

Comment: Citation: [Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/algo_)

Comment: Connecting a shortened version of a word to the full word in most cases should not require a reference.  Is that what the downvote was for?

Comment: I didn't downvote.. I thought they might have wanted a citation or something... just upvoted to 0 for you